# How to handle the error: <don't know to handle vector of type list>?

Tags: r

I am trying to save this dataframe as a csv, but I am getting the error

```
<Error in stream_delim_(df, path...., bom = bom, quote_escape = quote_escape): Don't know how to handle vector of type list>.
```

Here is my original code:

```r
write_csv(pland_elev_checklist, "data/pland-elev_location-year.csv")
```

The data, `pland-elev_location-year`, is a dataframe and not a list, so I do not know what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's some confusion here. (1) You say the data is `pland-elev_location-year` (which is a nonstandard object name in R due to the dashes), but you use `pland_elev_checklist`. (2) A `data.frame` can in fact include nested lists, for several reasons (not all of them good/intentional). Can you [edit] your question and provide the output from `dput(head(pland_elev_checklist))` in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question (would need a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) to do that well), but technically a data frame *is* a list. It's a list of columns. You can use this to your advantage at times, e.g. iterating across columns with a `*apply` function